# How to get json data via comma? Js

Tags: javascript

When trying to filter location data using comma but I get the error [object Object],[object Object],[object Object Object],[object Object]
Data json:

```json
{
  "command": "lok",
  "params": {
    "action": "test",
  },
  "response": {
    "skc": "D400",
    "location": [
      {
        "city": "Lond.",
        "location": "1m23"
      },
      {
        "city": "Lond.",
        "location": "2df65"
      },
      {
        "city": "Lond.",
        "location": "3sk56"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The js code looks like this:

```js
var lk = data.response.location;
console.log(lk);
var ghlok = lk.filter(function (item) {
        return item.location;
      }).join(",");
      console.log(ghlok);
```

`console.log(lk);` gives location in `{"city": "Lond.", "location": "1m23"}...`

`console.log(ghlok);` outputs `[object Object Object],[object Object],...`

I added `var par = JSON.parse(lk);` but I get the error

> Unexpected token 'o', "[object Object Object".... is not valid JSON

Comment: `filter` does not extract the `location` values as you appear to assume(?) - it _filters_ the original array, using the "truthiness" of `item.location` as criterion, whether to return an element or not. So what you are `join`-ing there is not an array of strings, but an array of arrays. This should be using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), not `filter`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var lk = data.response.location;
console.log(lk);

var ghlok = lk.map(function (item) {
  return item.location;
}).join(",");

console.log(ghlok);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to filter the array `lk` to include only elements that have a location, you can use `lk.filter(i => i.location)`. To use the `.join()` method, you need a string array. To convert your location object to a string, you can use `JSON.stringify()` as shown below before applying `join()`:

```
var ghlok = lk.filter(i => i.location)
              .map(i => JSON.stringify(i))
              .join(',')
```

it will output:

```
{"city":"Lond.","location":"1m23"},{"city":"Lond.","location":"2df65"},{"city":"Lond.","location":"3sk56"}
```